# Eclipse: Cant finish creating new C Project

Tags: c, eclipse-oxygen, gnu-toolchain

Hello dear Eclipse developer,

I am already pretty desperate about figuring out the following problem, and maybe you can be part of the solution.

So heres the Context:
I want to develop an application for a Nucleo STM32F401RE Microprocessor Developmentboard.

To do so i need to set up the Eclipse Oxygen 3 IDE for my Windows XP x86 OS as descriped in this guide: 
https://www.carminenoviello.com/2014/12/28/setting-gcceclipse-toolchain-stm32nucleo-part-1/

In short:

- Install Eclipse Oxygen 3
- Install C/C++ Development Tools
- Install the GNU ARM plug-ins for Eclipse
- Install the GCC ARM tool-chain
- Install the Build Tools
- Install the ST Link drivers for STM32Nucleo board

Every Step worked as expected and as descriped in the guide so far.

The next step is creating a test project, so I followed the project creation wizard for c/c++ projects in eclipse, which worked fine as well until i reached the very last step of the project creation wizard.

The last step wants me to select the path to the used Cross GNU ARM Toolchain which has already been installed in previous steps of the guide.
So i filled up the form fields, but the "Finish" and the "Next" Button stays greyed out! The "Back" Button is not working as well, so i literally cant do anything in this dialog field anymore, but cancel the project creating.

Someone went through this before and has an idea what the problem is and how to fix it?
Is it a bugg in eclipse?
Did i do something wrong ?

I've taken an Image to show what the problem is:

[image]

Thanks for your attention, dear developer. Good answers will make me a fan of yours.

**UPDATE**

Starting Eclipse with the errorlog console brought the following error when starting the project creation Wizard:

Managed Build system manifest file error: Duplicate identifier ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedBuild.cross.toolchain.lib.release for element type ToolChain

This is the first time i get in touch with eclipse.
Can someone explain what this means and how to get rid of it?

Comment: [Eclipse bug 512550](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512550) sounds like it, but it should already be fixed. What did you enter as project name? Is there anything in the log file?

Comment: project name was set to hello_world in the very first dialog of the wizard, what seemed to be working. I just updated the post with the latest research results. I guess the error shown above could be the reason.

Comment: Try the GNU MCU Eclipse bundle from https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/downloads/ rather then adding the plugins manually.

Comment: The duplicate identifier is reported as [Eclipse bug 513860](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513860) (two plug-ins mistakenly use the same ID for their extensions) which should also be fixed in Oxygen.3. I guess it causes of one of the plug-ins you installed. Please try the [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/oxygen3a) and install additional plug-ins only if required.

Comment: @(André & howlger) First of all thanks for your help ! I know, both of you got more important stuff to do! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @howlger You are right - uninstalling the GNU MCU Eclipse Plugin  solved the "Duplicate Identifier" Issue.

Comment: @(Andre & howlger) The Guide I already referred to in my question wants me to install the BuildTools using these files https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuarmeclipse/files/Miscellaneous/ which are obviously marked as deprecated. According to the instructions on the redirect-readme i tried to use Eclipse Marketplace to install them, what caused the error. Im not sure what is the workaround now ? Try installing them manually as described here https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/downloads/ ?

Comment: I'm no expert here, but the GitHub site looks promising to me and seems to be up-to-date. You might also ask in the [Eclipse CDT forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=80).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Photon and tried the installation through marketplace and manual installation of versions 4.4.1 and 4.3.3 but I'm still experiencing the same issue than you.

The solution was to uninstall Eclipse Photon and install Eclipse Oxygen 3a. Now the project creation works properly.

Regards.

Comment: Had the same experience with Eclipse 2019. Downgrading to Oxygen 3a resolved the issue where GNU MCU Eclipse Arm Embedded GCC was not available for selection and the GNU ARM Cross Toolchain dialog could not be Finished.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience for my first eclipse project. After checking the installation of plugins in the Eclipse IDE, I found there are two versions of GNU MCU C/C++ (...) installed. The problem solved by uninstalling one of them. Hopes that could help someone later. I spend the whole day to solve the problem! lol

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling GNU MCU does the trick and soled the issue.